# I can't disable checkbox?

Tags: c#, checkbox

I can't disable checkbox...

```
public  void seat_reser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string asd = "";

    DataTable dt = ob.dataview("Select * from seat_res where bus_id='"+ bus_select.Id+"'and date='"+bus_select.date +"'");

    foreach (DataRow d in dt.Rows)
    {
        asd += d[2].ToString();    // d[2] is seat column
        asd+=",";
    }

    box[0] = CheckBox1;
    box[1] = CheckBox2;
    box[2] = checkBox3;
    box[3] = checkBox4;
    box[4] = checkBox5;
    box[5] = checkBox6;
    box[6] = checkBox7;
    box[7] = checkBox8;
    box[8] = checkBox9;
    box[9] = checkBox10;
    box[10] = checkBox11;
    box[11] = checkBox12;
    box[12] = checkBox13;
    box[13] = checkBox14;
    box[14] = checkBox15;
    box[15] = checkBox16;
    box[16] = checkBox17;
    box[17] = checkBox18;
    box[18] = checkBox19;
    box[19] = checkBox20;
    box[20] = checkBox21;
    box[21] = checkBox22;
    box[22] = checkBox23;
    box[23] = checkBox24;
    box[24] = checkBox25;

    for (int h = 0; h < box.Length; h++)
    {
        box[h].Enabled = true;
    }

    string[] n = asd.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < box.Length; j++)
        {
            if (n[i] == box[j].Text)
            {
                box[j].Enabled = false;
                j++;
            }
            else if (!(box[j].Enabled == false))
            {
                box[j].Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add more detail

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please be so kind a format your code properly. Fix the indentation, remove lines which are empty or contain code unnecessary to understand the problem

Comment: What makes you unable to to disable them? an exception or some religious restriction?

Comment: its a bus reservation projects

Comment: Its a bus reservation project ,buses with 25 seats represented by using check box ,checkbox (S1,S2........S25) ,when selected and sumit it is saved in database comma separated eg S1,S2.but when select same bus for another reservation the seats which are already selected must disable on form load (which is a success)..I have a combobox and a search button on the same page which enables me to search more buses to the same location  on same date ,

Comment: when i select  another bus i want the seats already booked for that bus to be disabled and seats which are available to be enabled.....My problem lies there ,It is not disabling....

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, did you want to set the checkbox's **visibility** or **checked state** to false, instead of disabling it? Did you want to make it invisible or simply unchecked?

In that case you might want to change your usage of `Enabled` to `Visible` or `Checked`, for example, like this:

```
box[h].Visible = false;
box[h].Checked = false;
```

What's the difference between `Enabled`, `Checked` and `Visible`?

`Enabled` - this will enable/disable the checkbox, you cannot check or uncheck the checkbox if it is disabled, however, the checkbox will still be visible on screen

`Checked` - this will check/uncheck the checkbox, it's identical to user actually clicking the checkbox

`Visible` - this will make the checkbox visible/invisible, so that user cannot see the control, nor can he click on it or interact with it in any way

Comment: But when i select another bus from form with different seats booked the checkbox corresponding to that seat is not disabling

Comment: its a bus reservation project ,buses with 25 seats represented by using check box ,checkbox (S1,S2........S25) ,when selected and sumit it is saved in database comma separated eg S1,S2.but when select same bus for another reservation the seats which are already selected must disable on form load (which is a success)..I have a combobox and a search button on the same page which enables me to search more buses to the same location  on same date ,

Comment: when i select  another bus i want the seats already booked for that bus to be disabled and seats which are available to be enabled.....My problem lies there ,It is not disabling....

Comment: Well I guess you should be doing the same thing you're doing in your form load, if that is successful. Every-time you refresh the combobox/fill it with your elements, you should be disabling the ones that are disabled.. can't really help you because I don't understand most of your explanation..